# base64_decode changes when GET argument present

Tags: php, base64

I have a PHP script with this content:

```
$request_data='teststring';
var_dump($request_data);
$bd = base64_decode($request_data);
var_dump($bd);
die()
```

When I load the page, it outputs

```
string(10) "teststring" string(7) "��-���"
```

But, if I pass a GET string to the page - any string at all - it outputs this instead:

```
string(10) "teststring" string(7) "µë-²Úâž"
```

What is going on? How can passing a GET string to the page change the functionality of base64_decode? If I set $request_data to valid base64 encoded data, then the GET argument does nothing, and it decodes it correctly. But when it's an invalid string, it decodes it differently depending on the argument. Why is this? How can I fix it?

I am trying to pass in base64 encoded encrypted data, which sometimes decodes to non-ascii characters, and am finding that when that happens I get the wrong values back. I need a way to safely base64_decode any data, whether or not it is an alphanumeric string.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the same data, it's just the browser using a different character encoding in the two cases.

Comment: Are you encoding it as `base64_encode`?

Comment: What do you want to _decode_ the _non encoded_ string to?

Comment: @arkascha I don't, I just want to know why the decoding changes based on an unrelated variable.

Comment: Can you make sure the browser uses the same encodings in the two cases?

Comment: @Maerlyn Looks like you're right! It is different encoding. Maybe I should change this from a php question to a firefox question then.